# "Ambiguous base class" error in template context

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

I have this function template:

```
template <class TemplateArgument, template<class> class TemplateType>
TemplateArgument f(const TemplateType<TemplateArgument>& arg)
{
    return TemplateArgument();
}
```

When used like this, it fails to compile:

```
struct A {};
template <typename T> struct S {};
template <typename T> struct B : public S<T> {};

struct C : public B<A> {};

int main()
{
    f(C());
    return 0;
}
```

And the error message is:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:15:10: error: no matching function for call to 'f(C)'

     f(C());

          ^

<source>:2:18: note: candidate: template<class TemplateArgument, template<class> class TemplateType> TemplateArgument f(const TemplateType<TemplateArgument>&)

 TemplateArgument f(const TemplateType<TemplateArgument>& arg)

                  ^

<source>:2:18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

<source>:15:10: note:   'const TemplateType<TemplateArgument>' is an ambiguous base class of 'C'

     f(C());

          ^
```

Happens with GCC (any version) and clang (any version). Does not happen with MSVC. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/g/eWxeHJ

Why does this error occur? I fail to see any ambiguity, the "ambiguous base class" error usually occurs in multiple inheritance situations, does it not?
How can I make my code compile (deduce template arguments correctly)?

Note that I cannot edit the `A`, `B`, `C`, `S` classes and their relation to each other, I can only edit my function `f()` to accept these classes properly.

Comment: do you still need `TemplateType`? `struct C` is not templated.

Comment: The compiler is not sure whether to deduce `args` type as `B<A>` or `S<A>`.

Comment: @r3mus_n0x On the one hand I agree with you on the other hand shouldn't compiler choose the most derived of the alternatives?

Comment: @navyblue I wouldn't expect it to do anything automatically that is not explicitly specified in the standard. I've never read or heard of such a rule for template deduction.

Comment: @r3musn0x: oh, I see now... I, too, expected it to deduce the most derived class. Do you think it's a mistake in the C++ standard that the compiler isn't required to deduce this case automatically? Or is such deduction incompatible with the existing standard for some reason?

Comment: @codekaizer: Yes, I still do need `TemplateType` it as the function body needs to know it (and you can see that it happens to be the return type as well).

Comment: @r3musn0x: If what you say is indeed the source of compiler's confusion, why doesn't specifying the arguments explicitly work? `f<A, B<A>>(C())` also fails. This, however, does work: `f((const B<A>&)C());`

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, I was just about to suggest this same solution.

Comment: This is now functioning with the latest gcc and clang compilers, and I wonder whether that's a bug they've found and solved or a new bug they've introduced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler is not sure whether to deduce `arg`s type as `B<A>` or `S<A>`. I'm not sure about this specific case but MSVC is known to violate the standard especially when it comes to templates.

As for your function, you need to resolve this ambiguity yourself by explicitly casting to the appropriate base:

```
f((const B<A> &)C());
```

or by specifying template parameters explicitly:

```
f<A, B>(C());
```

Generally whenever there is any ambiguity in the language it is never automatically resolved by the compiler because it would just be a speculation about what exactly did user intend, which might be right in some cases and completely wrong in others.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, the second parameter is a template template parameter so it should be `f<A, B>(C())`, that is should be substituted with a non-instantiated template name.

Comment: Thanks, learned something new about template deduction today (and also, about the importance of paying attention to details!)